# 'Placeholder' text in an HTML or Blazor input control - Can it be 'lighter'?

Tags: html, css, blazor

I notice that on most sites (including Stack Overflow) that it is thankfully very clear to my eye when an input is merely displaying 'placeholder' text as opposed to the text I might type into the input.

And yet (unless I'm missing something) in my Blazor apps, the default 'placeholder' text seems to appear almost dark enough that it can easily be mistaken for actual input text.

I understand that I could compose 'placeholder' strings that are unlikely to ever be mistaken for actual input text, but I thought I'd ask this anyway; just in case there's an answer out there:

Is there a way to make 'placeholder' text look more like...well... 'placeholder' text?  For example, I'm doubtful, but is there a way for CSS just to address 'placeholder' font styling?

Comment: If you turn off CSS in any site you will see your browser's default style. There is nothing specific about Blazor or any other platform that would cause the rendered HTML to have a fundamentally different default style. If you inspect an empty input with placeholder text you can see what style is being applied in your browser's dev tools and then change it to get an idea of what CSS you want to apply to lighten the placeholder text.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to style the placeholders using CSS.
Let’s take a look at an example!

```css
input[type="text"]::placeholder{
  font-size:10px;
  opacity:0.7;
}

input[type="text"]#name::placeholder{
  opacity:1;
  font-weight:700;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Hello">

<input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name">
```

You can target a specific input field using id as shown in the code.